# Город Китеж

Tags: топонимика

Легенда говорит о городе Китеже, который вместе с жителями опустился на дно озера Светлояр. Но что означает само название города? От какого слова оно произошло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этимология топонима затруднительна. По Фасмеру, возможно от фин. kiides "глубокий грот", родственное ханты kiles "место для отдыха, выкопанное в снегу". Предполагается, что название города произошло от княжеского села Кидекши (от древнерус. «покинутое место») (около Суздаля), уничтоженного татаро-монгольской ордой в 1237 году. В других источниках нашла такое толкование: "Согласно одной из легенд, в районе озера Светлояр родились волшебный полуконь-получеловек Китоврас – могущественный волшебник и строитель древних храмов, а также бог мудрости и хмеля Квасура. От их имен и произошло название града Китежа" (http://www.perunica.ru/raznoe/5325-kitezh-grad.html).